# Mulesoft - Cloudhub deployment error: Deployment configuration is not valid, : No deployment configuration was defined

Tags: deployment, mulesoft, cloudhub

This is my build details in POM:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
         <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
         <extensions>true</extensions>
         <configuration>
            <deploymentType>${deploymentType}</deploymentType>
            <muleVersion>${muleVersion}</muleVersion>
            <redeploy>${redeploy}</redeploy>
            <businessGroup>${businessGroup}</businessGroup>
            <username>${username}</username>
            <password>${password}</password>
            <applicationName>${applicationName}</applicationName>
            <environment>${environment}</environment>
            <region>${region}</region>
            <workers>${workers}</workers>
            <workerType>${workerType}</workerType>
            <uri>${anypoint.uri}</uri>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>deploy</id>
               <phase>deploy</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>deploy</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.7.0</version>
         <configuration>
            <compilerArgs>
               <args>-parameters</args>
            </compilerArgs>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

These are my properties:

```
<properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
   <app.runtime>4.2.1</app.runtime>
   <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.2.7</mule.maven.plugin.version>
   <deploymentType>cloudhub</deploymentType>
   <muleVersion>4.2.1</muleVersion>
   <redeploy>true</redeploy>
   <businessGroup>****</businessGroup>
   <username>****</username>
   <password>****</password>
   <applicationName>****</applicationName>
   <environment>Sandbox</environment>
   <region>us-east-1</region>
   <workers>1</workers>
   <workerType>Micro</workerType>
   <anypoint.uri>https://anypoint.mulesoft.com</anypoint.uri>
</properties>
```

Following is my terminal command:

mvn clean deploy -DmuleDeploy -X
and I am getting following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project helloworld: Deployment configuration is not valid, : No deployment configuration was defined. Aborting. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project helloworld: Deployment configuration is not valid,
```

If I use following configuration, it deploys successfully in cloudhub:

```
<configuration>
   <cloudHubDeployment>
      <uri>${anypoint.uri}</uri>
      <muleVersion>${muleVersion}</muleVersion>
      <businessGroup>${businessGroup}</businessGroup>
      <username>${username}</username>
      <password>${password}</password>
      <applicationName>${applicationName}</applicationName>
      <environment>${environment}</environment>
      <region>${region}</region>
      <workers>${workers}</workers>
      <workerType>${workerType}</workerType>
   </cloudHubDeployment>
</configuration>
```

Not sure where I am doing wrong in the first config.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration in the first example is for the older version of the Mule Maven Plugin ([2.2.x](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/mule-maven-plugin-v2.2#deploying-to-cloudhub) or earlier) for Mule 3.x. The versions for Mule 4.x (3.3.x) always used the format of your second example. See the documentation at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/mmp-concept#deploying-to-cloudhub

The last version of the Mule Maven Plugin for Mule 3 [(2.3.x) uses the same format than the Mule 4 version](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/mule-maven-plugin#deploy-a-mule-application-to-cloudhub).

In summary, the first example is obsolete and not compatible with a Mule 4 deployment.

Comment: So if someone had a organization and was using `https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations/${project.groupId}/maven` but getting a Error 405 method not allowed on deployment, what does that mean? i.e. Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: I'm not sure why someone would use CloudHub deployment configuration with the Exchange Maven URL. Those are completely different things. If you want more details please post a new question, because it is a different topic than the one asked here.